# Compile time polymorphism with enums

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, enums, polymorphism

So, the questions is related to enum inheritance, and i seen a lot of topics here, in which described approaches how to write enum that support inheritance, but it is not the my case, I think.

I found some stuff that I would want to make. So the idea is that I have the class, let it be OpenGL texture class (actually it is) and there is enum that represent all possible values of one property in texture.

```
class Texture
{
    public:
        enum Filter
        {
            LINEAR   = 1,
            BILINEAR = 2,
            ANISOTROPIC = 3
        };

    public:
        Texture(Filter _filter)
            : filter(_filter) 
        { }

    private:
        Filter filter;
};
```

And class that inherits it. Enum in derived class must be redefined, but that I can use further in base class's constructor:

```
class Texture2d : public Texture
{
    public:
        enum Filter
        {
            LINEAR   = 1,
            BILINEAR = 2
        };

    public:
        Texture2d(Filter _filter)
            : Texture(_filter)
        { }
};
```

but, of course, this doesn't work, because newly created `Filter` is `Texture2d::Filter`, but not the `Texture::Filter`.

I tried to use an `enum class` like this:

```
class Texture
{
    public:
        enum class Filter;

    public:
        Texture(Filter _filter)
            : filter(_filter)
        { }

    private:
        Filter filter;
};

class Texture2d : public Texture
{
    public:
        enum Filter
        {
            LINEAR = 1,
            BILINEAR = 2
        };

    public:
        Texture2d(Filter _filter)
            : Texture(_filter)
        { }
};
```

But this is really stupid idea. I think, if I just would want to expand enum I would write some class wrapper, but I need to shrink enum too. So the question is, how to make this thing work on compile time? It is main problem - make this work in compile time. And another one question: actually trying to do such stuff is ok or I must check out architecture of my application?

(All answers will be appreciated)

Comment: Typo on first line, there is "Hello all)"

Comment: have you considered using a template instead of inheritance, that way the filter can be part of the class instead of having it separate as an enum.

Comment: It appears to me, you are complicating your design. Keep it simple (traditional 'is a' relationships).

Comment: So, i still think about architecture... The thing is that, for example, one type of texture has some properties and another one hasnt. And they must use one function to set actual value in Opengl. But worse, that another type, hasnt not a property by itself, but one or more possible state of this property. So, that is... 

Actually enum is looks like this:
enum class Filter

Comment: enum class Filter
{
    LINEAR = GL_LINEAR,
    NEAREST = GL_NEAREST,
    ...
}

So, actually enum holds opengl defines and i need to hold it or in opposite case i would to use function like this:

GLenum func(Filter filter)
{
    switch(filter)
    {
     case LINEAR:
        return GL_LINEAR;
      //and so on
    }
}

i dont like this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the problem with your code.
You just have to add a cast in your `Texture2d`'s constructor.

```
Texture2d(Filter _filter) // no Texture::Filter
    : Texture(static_cast<Texture::Filter>(_filter))
{ }

Texture t1(Texture::LINEAR);           // WORKS
Texture t2(Texture::BILINEAR);         // WORKS
Texture t3(Texture::ANISOTROPIC);      // WORKS

Texture2d t4(Texture2d::LINEAR);       // WORKS
Texture2d t5(Texture2d::BILINEAR);     // WORKS
Texture2d t6(Texture2d::ANISOTROPIC);  // ERROR
```

That's because `Texture2d::ANISOTROPIC` is interpreted as `Texture::ANISOTROPIC` because no `Texture2d::Filter::ANISOTROPIC` exists.

And since none of `Texture2d`s constructors accepts a `Texture::Filter` it results in an error.

Comment: O, thank you, i dont know how i can lost that!) But is this approach very elegant?

Comment: @1243scrat That depends on your definition of elegant. It does what you want and it's simple, so I guess it's fine.

Comment: Yea, it is really fine, thank you very much, Axalo! =)

Answer (score 0):

There is no inheritance with enums - so the extending/reducing idea is a nonstarter. What you could do instead is provide a conversion method in `Texture2d` between them:

```
class Texture2d : public Texture {
public:
    enum class Filter {
        LINEAR, BILINEAR
    };

    Texture2d (Filter f)
    : Texture(convert(f))
    { }

private:
    Texture::Filter convert(Filter f) {
        switch(f) {
        case Filter::LINEAR: return Texture::Filter::LINEAR;
        // etc.
        default: 
            // ? Maybe throw? 
     }
};
```

That let's you specify the list of valid enums in every subclass. It may be repetitive if you generally want to allow the same ones though.

Comment: Thanks, it is can take place too, i think, but seems like Axollo approach is simpler. Anyway thank you, it is good food for though)